# How to loop through multidimensional array and map field to key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an object structured like this:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 34,
    "parent": 0,
    "title": "Level 1 A",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "ID": 35,
    "parent": 0,
    "title": "Level 1 B",
    "children": [
      {
        "ID": 36,
        "parent": 35,
        "title": "Level 2 A",
        "children": [
          {
            "ID": 37,
            "parent": 36,
            "title": "Level 3 A",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "ID": 38,
            "parent": 36,
            "title": "Level 3 B",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I'm trying to loop through it and make the "title" the key so I end up with this:

```
[
  {
    "Level 1 A": {
      "ID": 34,
      "parent": 0,
      "title": "Level 1 A",
      "children": []
    }
  },
  {
    "Level 1 B": {
      "ID": 35,
      "parent": 0,
      "title": "Level 1 B",
      "children": [
        {
          "Level 2 A": {
            "ID": 36,
            "parent": 35,
            "title": "Level 2 A",
            "children": [
              {
                "Level 3 A": {
                  "ID": 37,
                  "parent": 36,
                  "title": "Level 3 A",
                  "children": []
                }

              },
              {
                "Level 3 B": {
                  "ID": 38,
                  "parent": 36,
                  "title": "Level 3 B",
                  "children": []
                }
              }
            ]
          }

        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I tried something like this, but it doesn't go through the children arrays so only the Level 1 elements get updated:

```
    for (var i = 0, l = response.length; i < l; i++) {
        map[response[i].title] = response[i];
    }
```

I believe I need to use some recursion, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get this done with Javascript. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your code to following

```
function updateArray(arr) {
    var updatedResponse = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        var obj = {};
        if(arr[i].children !== undefined) {
            arr[i].children = updateArray(arr[i].children);
        }
        obj[arr[i].title] = arr[i];
        updatedResponse.push(obj);
  }
  return updatedResponse;
}

var updatedArray = updateArray(response);
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/bXloL9VHxuxzOlZkHBTe?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @nikhil. I checked the plnkr link and it doesn't seem to add the new key in the children arrays, though, which is what I'm trying to do. Works for 1st level elements.

Comment: @MThomas, I missed that part. You need to do it the same way as done for response. Let me update the answer.

Comment: @MThomas - I have updated the answer, please review.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through multidimensional arrays, you need multiple nested `for` loops.

```
for(var i = 0, l = response.length; i < l; i ++){
    for(var j = 0, k = response.length; j < k; j ++){
        //Do some code here
    }
}
```

A general rule is for every dimension in the array, you need another loop.